# Check weather String is null in dart (nullsafety)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

How to check weather a text is null after null-safety update.

here my previous code

```
if (k.text != null) {
  print('not null');
} else {
  print('null');
}
```

How to perform same operation after null-safety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing much is change if u think `k.text` can be `null` then u just need to add `?` this symbol

e.g.

```
Object? k
```

so your code becames

```
if (k?.text != null) {
  print('not null');
} else {
  print('null');
}
```